# PhpStormのエラー表示について

Tags: phpstorm

ご閲覧ありがとうございます。

当方`PhpStorm`というIDEを試しに使用しています(無償使用期間)。
**cssファイルで「:」が抜けているなどのエラー表示が、該当ページを開かないと表示されません。(赤の下線が引かれない)**
いちいち開かないとエラー表示されないとなると、該当箇所がエラーのままpushしてしまいそうで非常に怖いです。

解決方法ありましたらお教えいただけると有難いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

【keyword】
- Windows10(64bit)
- PhpStorm w017.2.4 x64(無償使用期間)
- プロジェクトファイル総サイズ 34.0 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メニュー：`Code->Inspect Code`で プロジェクト全体のインスペクション実行 することが出来ます。(MAC版 phpstrom 2017.3 なのでメニューが違っていたらごめんなさい。)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！当方Windowsですが、お教えいただいた場所に`Inspect Code`がありました。エラー箇所は表示されるのですが、下線は引かれず…。これ以外にエラーを自動で検知するような方法は無いという解釈で相違ないでしょうか？？

Comment: はい、これ以外では無いです。（赤下線が引かれるエラー表示は、編集時のリアルタイムコード解析でエラー検知した時の表示です。）

Comment: そうなんですね…！丁寧に回答していただきありがとうございました！